# How to call a method using integer

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static int displayResult(int num1, int num2){
        return num1 * num2;
    }
public static void main(String args[]){
        displayResult(int num1, int num2);
    }
```

When I try to run my eclipse, it shows an error which is "the method displayResult(int,int) in the type method is not applicable for the arguments". Anybody can explain to me how it works? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you need to define `num1` and `num2` before you can use them.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int num1 = 3;
    int num2 = -4;
    displayResult(num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: public static float readNumber(){
 float number;
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter first number : ");
 number = sc.nextFloat();
 System.out.println("Enter second number : ");
 number = sc.nextFloat();
 return number;
}

But my num1 and num2 is based on user input.

Comment: First - if the user is providing float values, then your `displayResult` method needs to use float values too.  `public static float displayResult(float num1, float num2)` Second - you need both floats before you can call `displayResult()` but your code only has 1 float variable, `number`.  You need to store each float in its own variable, maybe `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`, then call your method: `displayResult(firstNumber, secondNumber)`.

Comment: public static int readNumber(){
  int num1, num2;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter first number : ");
  num1 = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter second number : ");
  num2 = sc.nextInt();
  return readNumber();
 }

I changed my code to become like this and now I am able to call the displayResult method. However, there is another error occurs. The console will keep prompt for user input for num1 and num2 like no ending. Is it my return readNumber() there got problem? I don know where should I return the result and go to the next method.

Comment: `return (readNumber());` just calls `readNumber()` over and over again!  I think you want to `return (displayResult(num1, num2));` maybe, to show the result of your calculation?

Comment: you're welcome!  if this answer (or another answer) was helpful, please consider voting for it or marking it as the accepted answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

When you call `displayResult` in `main`, you need to actually pass it *values*, rather than repeat the types and names of the arguments. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    displayResult(2, 3);
}
```

That should work, but it still won't do anything; `displayResult` returns the result, but it doesn't print it or do anything else with it. You likely want to print it, probably using `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass actual number values in the displayResult() in main. So change it to something like displayResult(1, 5); It's saying it doesn't like the arguments (int num1, and int num2) because it expects an (int, int) to be passed in like (1, 5).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with this? You need to pass integer values in to the parameters, the call you have does not do this. The integers are not initialized.
The following examples will compile:

```
public static int displayResult(int num1, int num2){
    return num1 * num2;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    displayResult(1, 1);
}
```

or...

```
public static int displayResult(int num1, int num2){
    return num1 * num2;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 1;
    displayResult(num1, num2);
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

When you write the following

```
public static int displayResult(int num1, int num2){
    return num1 * num2;
}
```

you're basically defining the method and specifying the argument types.

Invoking the method, however, is done as follows

```
displayResult(4,5);
```

Note that I can pass variables as well. The important point is that we don't give the type of the argument

Comment: That means I cannot use the user input number by this method? If I set the number inside method then the result displayed is going to be the same no matter what user has input. because I currently learning how to call a method based on user input.

Comment: Ok. What you can do is to set a variable to the user-entered value and then pass it to the method. How are you getting the user inputs? Are they passing them with the java command (command line parameters) or are you supposed to get the input after the program starts?